# "Multiplicity of implementation" - how to deal with it? And what's the 'name' of such thing?

Tags: c++, oop, implementation, interaction

My question is a bit about programming techniques or, maybe, design patterns. Suppose several classes derived from base which contains a pure virtual method that should do some interactions beetwen them.

For instance, `Rectangle`, `Ellipse`, `Triangle` and `Line` - all derived from a `Shape`. And this abstract class, `Shape`, contains `virtual bool Intersects(Shape* another) = 0`.

[It seems,](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/3963/moiqg.jpg) that I need to make six implementations, right (btw, is any better solution in this particular example?).

I have no idea of any other examples at the moment.

Maybe I'm talking about a thing that is well-known and I'm nearly sure there are some names describing the technique. However, I don't even know what to input to find it in the Internet.

Well, can you tell me how to implement such thing (I'm still wondering if any helper method is needed, or, maybe, `RTII`'s `dynamic_cast`?) or point some sources (arts, tutorials or whatever) about it?

Comment: Is run-time polymorphism really needed here?

Comment: I think nope, but I'd choose the best solution. It would be quite good if it was at least implemented with OOP.

Comment: I think you'll need ten functions - your count didn't include circle/circle intersections, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the school book example of double dispatch, the wikipedia article gives a good description of the problem and the solution:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch

If I remember correctly there's a very elegant solution to the problem in the book "Modern C++ Design" by Andrei Alexandescu

[http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Design-Generic-Programming-Patterns/dp/0201704315](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315)

Comment: Thanks, I think it's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm gonna read a lot about it. I was just searching the proper name of it. Hope you don't mind such posts.

Comment: @somnock The generalized problem is called *[multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch)*, so it has 'multiple' in the name. You weren't that far off the mark.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should search a bit more. However, if anybody will be searching putting my keywords he find the post :)

Answer (score 1):

The simple fact is that you are using inheritance incorrectly. Instead of having a Line, Box, Triangle kind of inheritance, you should instead have a VertexShape which represents all shapes that are composed of a series of vertices, and a FormulaShape which represents all shapes which are described by mathematical formulae.

Inheritance should not be used to model relationships that can be modelled by simply varying data which must be present in the class regardless- for example, the vertices used to build a polygon.

Edit: No, no, no. Use a *template*. Specialize it if you're desperate. That's what it's for. To provide zero-overhead generic algorithms. We discovered this stuff in the 90s, guys.

Comment: This is a bold statement without a complete definition of the problem. Maybe `Rectangles` and much more common than any other geometric figure in this particular problem, and you do not want to incur the cost of generic formulas for the area when a simple multiplication suffices... Maybe some operations in the domain can be applied to circles but not to ellipses, a `Line` is not a proper 2D figure...

Comment: DeadMG, you're right and I was even thinking about it. But it was only an example - but thanks for help in *this* particular situation. What do you, guys, think about add it to what David Rodríguez - dribeas said - an optimalization could be done - if there are collision between rectangle with rectangle (we calculate with min and max). Otherwise, we can compute it in more complex way, but thanks to it we don't have to provide a lot of implementations.

Comment: I think the whole idea of deriving from a `Shape` is a little misplaced here. Most geometric primitives are just too different. Having each primitive as a separate class and provide free functions for possible operations works much better imo.

Comment: @David: Use a template. That's what it's for.

Comment: @pmr: Okay, but I didn't think about polymorphism by an accident. If I have, for example, `Sprite` class for creating objects that could touch each other it's rather quite hard to do it with free functions. With virtual functions, I can put `Shape* area` member into a `Sprite` and simply check if a ball (circle) touches a tennis net (rectangle).

Comment: @DeadMG: You mean, for instance, to use template parameter with function's adreess to provide colliding algorithm, if needed?

Comment: @somnock: No. I mean to template on the type of the shape you're taking in.